# Numpy returns "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

Here is my code:

```
g = np.reshape(a,(len(a)/width,width)) 
p = g.astype(int) 
print(p)
```

Answer (score 4):

`len(a)/width` will return float

try `len(a)//width`

even better you can use -1 as first index and np will calculate for you

`np.reshape(a,(-1,width))`